# Java code not working to convert a binary to hexadecimal(which can also contain decimal values)

Tags: java, binary, hex, decimal

public class Question2 {

```
    //To convert INSERT NUMBER HERE to hexadecimal
    public static String binarytoHex(String number, int bin, int hex) {

    // Parse the number with source radix and return in specified radix(base) 
        return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(number, bin), hex); 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String x = "before"; // digits before decimal 

        String y = "after"; //digits after the decimal

        int bin = 2; // Source Base   
        int hex = 16; // Destination Base Hexadecimal 

        System.out.println("Binary to Hexadecimal: "+ binarytoHex(x, bin, hex) + "." + binarytoHex(y, bin, hex)); 
    } 
}
```

**This is the errors that are displayed in the console:**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "before" under radix 2
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
    at mathsassignment/mathsassignment.Question2.binarytoHex(Question2.java:9)
    at mathsassignment/mathsassignment.Question2.main(Question2.java:20)

Comment: Read the stacktrace and check what's on line 9 of your code - You're passing a string ("before") to Integer.parseInt. This doesn't work. You need to pass a String containing numbers like "123".

Comment: The exception is quite clear. You call `binarytoHex(x, bin, hex)`, where `x` contains `"before"`, then you pass that into `Integer.parseInt` but `"before"` is not a string that contains an integer

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string that is not a number to the binaryToHex method. Read the error message. It is quite helpful. String x needs to be assigned a number. `String x = "12";`